# Parsing/executing C# code in C++ (on Linux)?

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, language-binding

I want to be able to add scripting functionality to my application. One of the language bindings I am considering is C# (and possibly VB.Net).

The challenge is this:

1. My application is developed in C++
2. My application runs on Linux

I am aware of Mono, but I dont know (as yet), what is required to allow my C++ appliaction (running on linux), to be scriptable with .Net languages.

- Is this feasible?
- Am I crazy for even thinking of doing this?
- If I'm not crazy, can anyone provide some guidelines on how to go about implementing this?

Help, tips, ideas, suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Mono framework has an option specifically designed to allow embedding in C / C++ application. My suggestion would be to spend some time reading the documentation.